# How to prove that a set of numbers is a complete set of units modulo p, where p is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, coprime

[image: The original question.]

How do I show that if p is prime, then the following

${1, -1, 2, -2,..., \frac{p-1}{2}, -\frac{p-1}{2}}$

is a complete set of units modulo p?

[image: My attempt at a solution.]

Comment: What do you need now? The proof is complete in the first two lines of your answer itself.

Comment: It looks like you see that it's true for $p=5$.

Comment: So you're saying that as is my proof is sufficient? @DevanshKamra

Comment: Yes @PM2Ring , I tried showing that it works for 5, but I ultimately need to show that it works for all prime p.

Comment: Well, you should show that $p-1, p-2$ etc correspond to the numbers $>\frac{p-1}2$. That is, all the (non-zero) residues are covered, with no gaps, and no duplicates.

Comment: Oh ok, would it be something like $p-1$ is even so it is divisible by 2 and gives a number smaller than $p-1$ ??? @PM2Ring

Comment: No, I don't think that will help. First, show that your set $\{1, p-1, 2, p-2, ...\}$ has $p-1$ elements. That should be easy. And obviously they are all in the range from 1 to $p-1$. Then you just need to show that no 2 elements in the set are congruent mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ne y\in\{1,-1,2,-2,\dots,\dfrac{p-1}2,-\dfrac{p-1}2\}$, then $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|\le2\cdot\dfrac{p-1}2=p-1\implies x\not\equiv y\bmod p$.

Alternatively, if $x\equiv y\bmod p$, then $x\equiv a\bmod p$ has two solutions in $\Bbb Z_p$, a contradiction.